# GO: Add to map using for loop

Tags: for-loop, dictionary, go

I have been trying to add to a map using a for loop in golang but I haven't been able to do so. Could anybody give a simple example of how it could be done?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to do? [Here](http://play.golang.org/p/f42x8rBNDC) I'm adding to a map in a loop, but I don't think this is what you're trying to do.

Comment: It is a little unclear what you are trying to do. You can most certainly add 'stuff' to maps in loops. For a detailed walk trough on maps please read this: http://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action

Comment: Thanks Tyson!! For some reason my syntax was weird in my code but I managed to fix it with the snippet provided by you :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Moving from a comment to an answer.)

```
myMap := make(map[int]string)
for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
    myMap[i] = fmt.Sprintf("iteration %d;", i)
}
```